# passing data from an activity to another and getting an error when passing and EditText

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to pass a string in an EditText from LoginActivity to TwoActovity and this is the code:

LoginActivity (when a button is clicked)

```
var userName: String = editText.toString()

val i = Intent(this@LoginActivity, TwoActivity::class.java)
i.putExtra("userNamePass", userName)
startActivity(i)
}
```

TwoActivity

```
class TwoActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var userNamePassed: String

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_two)

        var int:Intent = intent
        userNamePassed = int.getStringExtra("userNamePass")
        textView10.text = userNamePassed


    }
}
```

this is the error message I get after entering a name in LoginActivity and clicking the button (it goes to TwoActivity but shows this message insted of the name I actually typed in LoginAvtivity):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wZHQ.png)

in the LoginActivity if I passed "any string in double quotation" instead if userName like the following code it works

```
//var userName: String = editText.toString()

val i = Intent(this@LoginActivity, TwoActivity::class.java)
i.putExtra("userNamePass", "anything")
startActivity(i)
}
```

Comment: var name: String = editText.text.toString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you're not getting an error, it's just string value of your `EditText` because you said `editText.toString()`.

What you really want is `editText.text.toString()`.